# Assertion with Hashmap - to verify the actual and expected data in selenium webdriver with testng with java

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have done a comparison over stored string values with expectedvalues in hashmap provided.

But I am totally stuck on below points:

1. I am able to verify the items, but if that particular string (suppose e.g 100) is present anywhere in the detailed page, then it is passing, which is an incorrect way of assertion.

   If I put

   ```
   //  Assert.assertEquals(allEle, entry.getValue());
   ```

   it is not working properly.
2. If I use 2 list to compare the expected and actual values, then how to show in result that date is failed or name is failed/passed.
3. My actual data is stored string values in a variable like in allElement arraylist I have stored all the text values by `gettext()`, which is my detailed view web page.
   And Expected data has been store in hashmap key value pair

Please see the below code for the reference

```
Map<String,String> expectedDataMap=new HashMap<String,String>();            
  expectedDataMap.put("Date", SalesInvoiceDate);
  expectedDataMap.put("Bank Voucher Number", DeliveryDocumentNumber);
  expectedDataMap.put("Total Amount", totalBaseAmountBV);
  expectedDataMap.put("Total Balance Amount", totalBalanceAmountBV);
  expectedDataMap.put("Total Paid Amount", totalPaidAmountBV);
  expectedDataMap.put("Bank Name", "Axis Bank-10100001");
  expectedDataMap.put("Vendor Name", "-50000017");
        
    List<WebElement> allOptions=driver.findElements(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(objectname)));
    
    List<String> allEle=new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(WebElement ele:allOptions)
    {
       allEle.add(ele.getText());
        
    } 
            //String actual=ele.getText();
     for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:expectedDataMap.entrySet())
     {
         if(allEle.contains(entry.getValue()))
            {
               //  Assert.assertEquals(allEle, entry.getValue());
                 
                System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ " is Passed:- "+entry.getValue());
         
            
         System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ "is Failed:- "+entry.getValue());
              
                 System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
            }
         }
```

How can I always reuse this function in different forms to assert the values and print it with expected key pair?

Comment: `allEle` is a list and `entry.getValue` is a String. So why are you expecting `Assert.assertEquals(allEle, entry.getValue());` to work?

Comment: but is it working and displaying pass or fail...my only concern is i have to assert exact match of expected data with actual data.In My case suppose 100 is anywhere on that detailed page then it is passing which is not correct way of verification

Comment: By "not working" I meant that `Assert.assertEquals(allEle, entry.getValue());` would always fail. Maybe you intended to use `Assert.assertTrue(allEle.contains(entry.getValue()))`

Comment: yeah thanks for suggestion i tried it ....but i purposely failed one item then why my test case didnt fail like assertion is the har assertion if only single item is got failed whole method fails

First product is:-- is Failed:- 1 KG Lyee box
expectedDataMap.put("First product is:-- ", "1 KG Lyee box");    Actual product is 1 KG Lychee box

Comment: It is not clear what you meant by `...if only single item is got failed whole method fails....`. From your example, the expected data is different from the actual data, so the test should be marked as **failed**

Comment: because assert is the hard assertion know so if only one item fails it should not proceed ahead....and i got it now that my expected data is different from actual...now what can i do so that i can reuse this assert method again and again ...i tried with created 2 hashmaps also by putting expected and actual data but that is also not working in my case

Comment: What do you mean by `reuse this assert method again and again` ??

Comment: means if i created assert() once in my keyword.java then i should reuse that function in my excel sheet....in excel sheet i can change the expected data eveytime so the main funciton will remain same no change

Comment: instead of hard-coding data to  `expectedDataMap`, load the data from excel. You could use a library like `apache-poi` for loading data from excel.